# Range of a Rhombus

Tags: c++, range, diamond-problem

I want to make a function to check if a point is in range of a rhombus or not ,

```
Bool Conditional::InRange(Point P)
{
    if( (P.x > Position.x-100) && (P.x < Position.x+100) &&
        (P.y > Position.y-60)  && (P.y < Position.y+60))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I end up with a rectangular range how to make this range be a rhombus ?? , where position is the center and the height =120 width =200

Comment: First a tip: any function like `if (foo) return true; else return false;` should be written more simply `return foo;`.

Comment: @Nate please refer for mathematical explanation http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312403/how-do-i-determine-if-a-point-is-within-a-rhombus

Comment: Are there any geometric restrictions on your rhombus? Does its 'bottom' edge sit flat to your plane?

Answer (score 0):

Rhombus co-ordinates are A,B,C,D

and the point is P which we need to check.

Find Angles between

pa,pb - angle1

pb,pc - angle2

pc,pd - angle3

pd,pa - angle4

Now if sum of all angles is 360 or -360 then P is inside of ABCD 
else it lies outside.

Angle You can find using slope intercept form.

i.e. m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

After You Found slope e.g.
 for pa line segment slope is m1 
 for pb line segment slope is m2 
 then angle can be calculated via tan(angle) = (m1-m2)/(1+m1*m2);

OR

you can use this link

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but how can I get the angle through the slope ??

Comment: @Nate After You Found slope e.g. for pa line segment slope is m1 and for pb line segment slope is m2 then angle can be calculated via
tan(angle) =  (m1-m2)/(1+m1*m2);

Comment: Thanks again I hope am not disturbing you :)  , but I need the angle so I get tan inverse for the answer ?